# Stop all container's with specific string in name using PODMAN

Tags: containers, podman

I have to stop all container's with specific string in name.
For example there is 4 container's with name's :
apache1 apache2 apache3 jboos

I try to stop only this with "apache" in the name.
Is there any native way in PODMAN to stop all containers with a specific name?

I can list the containers with the specified name:

```
podman ps -a -f name=apache
```

But is it possible to stop only container's from above output ?

Or maybe there is another way to achieve this result?

Comment: Maybe relevant. The very latest Podman has new filtering functionality: https://github.com/containers/podman/releases/tag/v4.0.0-rc2 _All commands that support filtering their output based on labels (e.g. podman volume ls, podman ps) now support labels specified using regular expressions (e.g. --filter label=some.prefix.com/key/*)._

Answer (score 0):

You can get a list of the container ids using

```
docker ps -q -f name=apache
```

Then you can use that somewhere else. I'm not familiar with podman, but you can kill the containers using docker like this

```
docker kill $(docker ps -q -f name=apache)
```

Please be aware that this will kill any container with a name that contains 'apache'. A container called 'im-nginx-and-not-apache' will match and will be killed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately in the case of podmana it is not successful

podman kill $(podman ps -q -f name=apache)

Error: you must provide at least one name or id

Comment: Does `podman ps -q -f name=apache` list any container ids? The error seems to indicate that it doesn't.

Comment: Thank you ! 
That's working:

podman rm -f $(podman ps -a -q -f name=apache)

Answer (score 0):

Try `podman stop --filter name=apache`

https://docs.podman.io/en/stable/markdown/podman-stop.1.html